# Is it possible to make a Poller (or PollableMessageSource) to poll messages as List?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Following the example found in GitHub https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-polling-binder-sample regarding polling messages from a PubSub subscription, I was wondering...

Is it possible to make a `PollableMessageSource` retrieve `List<Message<?>>` instead of a single message per poll?

I've seen the `@Poller` notation only being used in `Source` typed objects, never in `Processor` or `Sink`. Is it possible to use in such context when for example using `@StreamListener` or with a functional approach?

Answer (score 0):

The `PollableMessageSource` binding and `Source` stream applications are fully based on the `Poller` and `MessageSource` abstraction from Spring Integration where its contract is to produce a single message to the channel configured. The point of the messaging is really to process a single message not affecting others. The failure for one message doesn't mean to fail others in the flow.

On the other hand you probably mean GCP Pub/Sub messages to be produced as a list in the Spring message payload. That is really possible, but via some custom code from Pub/Sub consumer and `MessageSource` impl. Although I would think twice to expect some batched from the source. Probably you may utilize an aggregator to build some small windows if your further logic is about processing as list. But again: it is going to be a single Spring message.

May be better to start thinking about a reactive function implementation where you indeed can expect a `Flux<Message<?>>` as an input and Spring Cloud Stream framework will take care for you how to emit the data from Pub/Sub into the reactive stream you expect.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_reactive_functions_support

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Artem! Is there any example on how to consume a Flux<?> into a fixed size list, treat it accordingly, and keep processing? Still messing with how it blocks, throwing exceptions while trying to do such and so... So a starting point would be awesome!

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a good idea to collect list for the streaming flux. We definitely don't know when the queue on the broker is going to end. Right, never. Therefore a `Flux` you get as a input for your function is still hot. So, trying to collect it into a single list is not going to work. You may consider ` buffer()` operator though, but that's already a different story...